# haystack django errors on the field 'django_ct'

Tags: django, python-2.7, solr

Could anyone help me why `django_ct` does not exist and why the solr_backend is trying to access this field? have I missed any setup?

```
> Environment:
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL: ## http:\\mysit\search\searchresults\?searchtext=abcd ##
> Django Version: 1.4.2


>Python Version: 2.7.3



>Installed Applications:


>(...


> 'haystack',


> ...')




>Traceback for the error below:


>File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response


>  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)


>File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view


>  48.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


>File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_conneg-0.9.4-py2.7.egg/django_conneg/views.py" 

>in dispatch


>  241.             return super(ContentNegotiatedView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


>File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_conneg-0.9.4-py2.7.egg/django_conneg/views.py" 

>in dispatch


>  75.         return super(BaseContentNegotiatedView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


>File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch


>  69.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)


>File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataplace/web/search/views.py" in get


>  195.         logger.info("title count =" + repr(sqs.facet_counts()))


>File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/query.py" in facet_counts


>  510.             return clone.query.get_facet_counts()


>File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/backends/__init__.py" in get_facet_counts


>  656.             self.run()


>File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/backends/solr_backend.py" in run


>  693.         results = self.backend.search(final_query, **search_kwargs)


>File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/backends/__init__.py" in wrapper


>  34.             return func(obj, query_string, *args, **kwargs)


>File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/backends/solr_backend.py" in search


>  133.         return self._process_results(raw_results, highlight=kwargs.get('highlight'), 

>result_class=kwargs.get('result_class', SearchResult), distance_point=kwargs.get('distance_point'))


>File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/haystack/backends/solr_backend.py" in _process_results


>  371.             app_label, model_name = raw_result[DJANGO_CT].split('.')


>Exception Type: KeyError at /search/searchresults/


>Exception Value: u'django_ct'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your schema.xml file is not up to date.

You have to run:

```
python manage.py build_solr_schema
```

and copy the content of the output into your solr schema.xml file.
Here are the [docs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/management_commands.html#build-solr-schema) for that command.

Comment: Thank you laidibug. I did that and restarted solr. When i access locathost:8080/solr , i get loads of errors due to the new schema. Upon more research : http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backend_support.html#id1 suggests solr>3.5 . I initially installed solr-tomcat  which has a lower solr version. How can I install solr>=3.5 with tomcat 6?

Comment: You could install solr manually instead of using solr-tomcat and that will get you a newer version. I found a good article with some instructions here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-solr-on-ubuntu-14-04